# NGraphics converting SVG to PNG does not scale the image properly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ngraphics

I have svg icon that I am trying to convert to PNG. I am trying to make the PNG 100x100 pixels, but instead of scaling the image to this size, it gets cropped. What I am doing wrong?

```
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(svgpath))
        {
            SvgReader svgReader = new SvgReader(reader);
            Graphic gr = svgReader.Graphic;
            Size size = new Size(100, 100);
            var c = PlatformSupport.CreateImageCanvas(size);
            gr.Draw(c);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            c.GetImage().SaveAsPng(stream);
            byte[] fileContent = stream.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes(resultPath, fileContent);                
        }
```